# Node.js server connecting to another server

Tags: node.js, websocket, server

I need a nodejs server to connect to another nodejs server.
I am using the websocket npm package.

I used the code from the npm websocket documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

However, when I run my code, it returns error 502 bad gateway.

I am running the code in a glitch.com project.

The code for the server that is connecting: (which receives 502)

```
  var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
  var sclient = new WebSocketClient();
  sclient.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
      console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
  });
  sclient.on('connect', function(connection) {
      connection.on('error', function(error) {
          console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
      });
      connection.on('close', function() {
          console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
      });
      connection.on('message', function(message) {
          
      });
  });
  sclient.connect('ws://dev-rocketer-main.glitch.me/', 'echo-protocol');
```

Code for the server that receives the connection:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
const listener = server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
});
var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
       
    });
});
```